# Setting up FTP users on Linux

Tags: ftp

I've just installed vsftpd, and started the service, but now what?

- How and where do FTP users get set up?
- I've got a wordpress install that needs to use FTP.  Should I set up a special user for it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally users are setup as system users. These instructions are the commands, but you may need to change some things such as username and directories to match the username you want and where wordpress is installed.

1. `useradd wordpress-admin -d /var/www/html/wordpress`
2. `chown -R wordpress-admin:wordpress-admin /varwww/html/wordpress`
3. `passwd wordpress-admin`

Edit your vsftpd configuration and verify these settings:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=yes
write_enable=yes
```

This will allow wordpress to login via ftp and make any changes required. http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html covers the options in the vsftpd configuration file.